# JScrollPane with JList does not scroll in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist, gridbaglayout

I have a couple of Jlist within jscrollpanes in a gridbaglayout. 
The amount of entries in 1 Jlist is more than fits in the visible area of the Jlist. 
But the jscrollpane does not provide scrolling functionality.

I used to have the all of the jscrollpanes enclosed in a jpanel, at that time scrollpane provided the correct scrolling functionality.

I have the preferredsize of the Jlist set to [0,0]. The layout of the Jlist is correct.
I can set the preferredsize of the JList to an explicit value of for example [80,300]. This causes JList to be scrollable partially. The real size of the JLIst, if it would be visible completely, is much longer.

Somehow I guess the gridbaglayout is resizing my Jlist in a way that the Jlist is not able to provide the correct size it has to the scrollpane.

How do I make the gridbaglayout and Jlist within jscrollpanes work together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set preferred sizes of `JScrollPane`'s content. Set preferred size for the `JScrollPanes` instead.

Comment: Setting the preferred sizes of the Jlist to "null" fixed the problem. I also set the preferred sizes of the Jscrollpane's to "null".

Comment: don't use setXXSize (with a not-null dimension), ever. As you experienced, @WillamS , _removing_ the interference with the component's internal bookkeeping (by nulling it) removed the problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thx. I had same problem and preferred sizes (reset to [0,0]) fixed this up.

Comment: you mean new Dimension(0, 0)? That sounds strange ... because setting any not-null value will short-circuit the default calculations (which is a bad thing!)